# Очистить текст из файла на c#

Tags: c#, файлы, form

Пожалуйста помогите мне. Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку, очистился весь текст в файле.

Есть вопросы, задавайте мне.

Вот мой код:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PathFile = @"D:\ds\database.txt";
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        
        File.Delete(PathFile);

        string test = "hello";

        File.Create(PathFile);
        lines.Add(test);
        File.WriteAllLines(PathFile, lines);
    }
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что выдает мне ошибку. Помогите мне пожалуйста.

Comment: Всегда пишите, какое именно исключение вам выдает приложение. Именно здесь ошибка очевидна, но больше не рассчитывайте на телепатию отвечающих.

Comment: Исправьте текст вопроса, добавьте в него точный текст ошибки, чтобы будущим посетителям было понятно, что именно у вас приозошло. Вопрос можно редактировать.

Comment: @aepot Ок, теперь я буду знать. (в следующий раз когда у меня будет вопрос, буду писать точно :) ).

Comment: Вы и в этот раз тоже можете добыть текст ошибки. Известно же, как ее вызвать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короткий ответ: попытка открыть уже открытый с монопольным доступом на чтение файл вызвала исключение.

Вы перемудрили. `File.Create(PathFile);` не просто создает файл, а открывает его. Обычно этот метод используют так.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    // здесь запись в файл
}
```

`FileStream` это `IDisposable` объект. Он держит файл открытым, пока вы его не задиспозите через `using`, `Close()` или `Dispose()`. Ошибка возникает, когда вы повторно обращаетесь к уже открытому файлу.

То есть проблему можно легко исправить вот так:

```
File.Create(PathFile).Close();
```

Но вы слишком много делаете лишних манипуляций.

Логику файла в вашем коде можно прочитать так:

- удалить файл
- открыть файл на перезапись с полной очисткой, создать, если не существует (здесь не хватает "закрыть")
- открыть файл на перезапись с полной очисткой, создать, если не существует, записать туда строки, закрыть файл

Зачем столько раз делать одно и то же?

Исправленный код

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PathFile = @"D:\ds\database.txt";
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    string test = "hello";
    lines.Add(test);
    File.WriteAllLines(PathFile, lines);
}
```

Содержимое файла будет просто перезаписано. Если файла нет, он будет создан автоматически.

Чтобы дозаписать строчки в конец не удаляя предыдущие, то надо использовать `AppendAllLines`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. И извините за мой странный вопрос. Я просто учусь в язык программирование c# :)